# Android Kotlin callback with unkown number of arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

i'm creating a function like this:

```
fun someFunction(
    callBack: () -> Unit
){
    callback.invoke()
}
```

when i will use the function:

```
someFunction(
    callBack = callBackFun()

)
```

So the question is, since i don't know, how many parameter callBackFun() will have(could be 0 or multiple) since someFunction could be use in multiple situation. how can i create the callback with 0 or more argument (vararg didn't work in this situation)

Comment: Do you expect the body of `someFunction` to provide the values of these arguments, or does it only call `.invoke()` with 0 args like this? This is the important question. If it's only calling invoke like this, then the type `() -> Unit` is fine. The problem is that you're not passing the function correctly on the call site: pass a lambda with braces `callBack = { someFun(42, "bob") }` (or a function reference) and you can put anything inside the lambda (if you know a set of arguments already on the call site)

Answer (score 3):

You put `callBackFun()` inside two curly braces `{}` and you will be able to pass any function with different arguments:

```
someFunction(
    callBack = { callBackFun() }
)

someFunction(
    callBack = { secondCallBackFun(arg1, arg2) }
)

someFunction(
    callBack = { thirdCallBackFun(arg1, arg2, arg3) }
)
```

And you can even pass multiple functions and write any logic you want inside the lambda it's just like any other function:

```
someFunction(
    callBack = { 
        val arg1 = "test"
        val arg2 = "test2"
        val arg3 = 21

        callBackFun()
        secondCallBackFun(arg1, arg2)
        thirdCallBackFun(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    }
)
```

But callBack lambda function arguments should be known, you are setting its type as: `() -> Unit` so it's not taking any argument.

Comment: this work well, i will only keep the issue about composable from lambda :-P

Comment: I don't understand, you want to pass composable function inside the lambda argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `vararg` inside your callback function is not supported right now, you can use `List` if you like:

```
fun someFunction(
    callBack: (args: List<Any>) -> Unit
){
    callback.invoke(listOf<Any>())
}
```